# EDITOR environment variable changes after reboot

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, editor, less

While running the `less` command, pressing <kbd>v</kbd> opens the file inside the editor. I have set the `EDITOR` environment variable to `vi` by running the command `export EDITOR=vi`.

It works perfectly fine as expected. However when I reboot the computer, the editor is no longer Vi. How do I make it permanent?

Comment: Please set that in your `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually configure this behaviour globally using `update-alternatives`:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config editor
There are 4 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I've already selected Vim, but `nano` is the Ubuntu default. You would type `3` to select Vim in my example, if it weren't already selected.

As well as `less`, any program that calls an editor (such as `sudoedit`) should now call the selected one.

Comment: +1; didn't think about that option as I answered here too :)

Comment: It's an amazing option but gets lost in all the traffic :-)

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. I also did "man update-alternatives" to resolve the curiosity.

Answer (score 8):

To make it permanent simply do the following in terminal:

```
echo "export EDITOR=vi" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This will add the line to your `.bashrc` file which gets called every time you open a terminal window.

To answer why this will work even if there has been a similar line before added to `.bashrc` is simple. `.bashrc` is a script with will be read and executed in a linear way, and this method is adding this line as the last below all others, so it gets executed/evaluated as last. So if there has been a line before the value of the `EDITOR` variable will be overwritten by the line you add.

Alternatively, if you not want to create a mess you can as well using your favorite editor (vi, vim, nano, joe etc..) to do this change and add a line if none is present and if one is present edit it.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to add it to your `.bashrc` file, open it with `nano` or `vi` and add the following line:

```
export EDITOR=vi
```